# Bootstrap 4 carousel containing navbar

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to put a navbar in my carousel. Since bootstrap 4 came out I'm using it but I want my navbar to overlap my carousel. Because now if I just open my site it shows it but I need to scroll down so I just want to overlap my navbar the carousel.

This is my navbar code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">...</a>
</nav>
```